# saving custom scripts in matomo tag manager results in 403

Tags: matomo, piwiktracker

As soon as I add `<script> ... </script>` to a "custom html" tag in Matomo Tag Manager and hit "save", there is a network request error 403 saying "You don't have permission to access this resource. Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

- Saving without the "script tag" works just fine e.g. I can embed the text "abc" and publish it.
- I am logged in with a super admin account.
- I tried to create a new tag from scratch.

This one fails when I click "save":

```js
<script> abc </script>
```

This one succeeds when I click "save":

```js
abc
```

Actual behavior: saving fails

Expected behavior: saving succeeds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that you are using a Web Application Firewall (WAF) like `mod_security` that blocks form submissions (and therefore POST parameters) that contains HTML.